Rather Than Framing Causal Inference as "How Much X Causes Y to Change", Can You Frame Causal Inference As "X Explains _% of the Variation in Y"
Most causal research designs seek to estimate a causal effect and interpret that causal effect as a marginal effect (a 1-unit shift in X leads to a _ amount of change in Y).
However, as I've spent more time applying causal inference practices in industry, it seems like stakeholders want to know more than just this. For example, how does the effect of X1 compare to that of X2? How impactful is X1 compared to the entire range of variables that might cause a change in Y?
These are questions that don't seem to be easily answered by the paradigm that I'm used to where we are focused on a very narrow estimand rather than how our estimate fits into the entire DGP that explains Y. Something I've seen done a lot in older studies is "X explains _% of the variation in Y". Due to their age and sometimes poor methodology, I'm always skeptical that these studies are actually estimating how much of Y is caused by X. Still, it has got me thinking. Are there methods to go about estimating comparative effect sizes? (By comparative, I mean the effect of X compared to all other things that impact Y to gauge substantive significance of a given treatment)?

If you don't want to assert causality, just a relationship, then are you really doing causal inference?

In a causal inference context, what exactly would you mean by "explains variation"?

@Dave I was not trying to imply in my query that I wasn't trying to assess causality. Figuring how much of Y is caused by X, and the more traditional question of how much X impacts Y are both causal questions, no?

@whuber In my mind, I am thinking of this like you would if you were to simulate data. We could simulate the DGP that explains all variation in Y (we could even assume no noise for the sake of the hypothetical). How much of Y is explained by X? We can estimate that a 1-unit increase in X -> a 0.2-unit increase in Y. But this doesn't tell us how this 0.2-unit increase compares to all other causes of variation in Y.
